# Adding JAVA_HOME to Linux - correct way

Tags: java, linux

I have downloaded oracle jdk tarball, and extracted it to `/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_172` directory.

I provided 755 permission to '/usr/lib/java/` directory recursively.

I then went ahead and changed my `/etc/environment` script to be:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Then typed:

`source /etc/environment`

and typed `java -version` to confirm that it's recognised.

Once I logged off, everything is gone. And I cannot even find this after opening a new shell. I want this to work for any user, but cannot remember whether i have to add this to `.bashrc` or some other file?

In other words, do i need to provide group access to this, or simply add the environment variables?

Comment: you can find the way to set environment variable here https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: try adding `source /etc/environment` into .bashrc file in your home directory, and then open terminal and refresh variables from `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle he says "I want this to work for any user". Relying on `.bashrc` means you'd need to update that for all users, including any new ones added in future.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is, add a file to /etc/profile.d, along the lines of

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

This should be executed for every user on login.

One additional thing is, that I normally install the respective "current" java version under /usr/local, e.g. /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_172 and softlink this to /usr/java. That way I can easily upgrade and eventually switch back and forth without modifying and /etc-scripts. (Note: probably the best practices today recommend other directories than the ones I usually use ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following in one go and it worked.

1) Added `source /etc/environment` to my `/etc/profile`

2) Typed `source /etc/profile`

3) exited the bash fully

4) Reopened the bash as sudo and typed `java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

But I think this is also, because I provided 755 access to `/usr/lib/java` recursively.

I had to go this extra mile because I am doing a proper "Sandboxed" development in those machines which have only intranet connectivity, and cannot see past that firewall :( 
Otherwise, an `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless` would be my prefered option.